# How could Thomas Edison file a patent before he was born?

Tags: error-detection

In reference to the patent: [US465972](https://www.google.com/patents/US465972)

I've noticed that this Google Patents page lists the filing date of a patent as Apr 10, 1839, but that's before the inventor, Thomas Edison, was born. How could this be?

Answer (score 1):

Filing date mentioned in Google Patent is wrong, actual filing year is 1889 actual pdf file contains correct date.

[image]

due to error in OCR software it is incorrectly mentioned as 1939.